# HTML THIS statement

Tags: javascript, html

```
<head>
<script>
function copyText(str1, str2){
    document.getElementById(str2).innerHTML = document.getElementById(str1).innerHTML
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="main">
    <H2 id="text1">Hello World</H2>
    <H2 id="text2" >No change so far</H2>
    <button onclick="copyText(document.main.text1.id, document.main.text2.id)">Change</button>
</body>
```

I want to able pass element ids as parameters to javascript functions. Is there a way to this?

Comment: Why wouldn't `copyText('text1', 'text2')` work?

Comment: You need a semicolon after your declaration on line four.

Comment: And what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Who taught you to reference elements via `document.main.text1.id`? yikes.

Comment: Semicolons are not mandatory outside inline event handlers and a few special places

Comment: @mplungjan Technically you are right, but it's a good habit to have IMO. Plus you might run into problem with linting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decent cross-browser way to get elements by ID is the `document.getElementById()` function you already know about. So rather than this:

```
document.main
```

... you should do this:

```
document.getElementById("main")
```

... etc. But of course you are doing something redundant: get an element by ID in order to obtain its ID. It's like making a phone call to ask the receiver for its phone number. All you need is:

```
copyText('text1', 'text2')
```

IDs as just strings.